# how to get the latest data in the postgresql database using the golang fiber programming language with GORM?

Tags: postgresql, go, fibers

i've created a struct

```go
    type Humid struct {
        Id        int
        Sensor_id int
        Value     float32
        CreateAt  time.Time
    }
```

and this is to connect to db

```go
    func PostgreSQL() {
        dsn := "host=localhost user= password= dbname= port= sslmode=disable TimeZone=Asia/Shanghai"
        connection, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
        fmt.Println("Connected!")
        if err != nil {
            panic("Could not connect to database")
        }
        DB = connection
    }
```

in this function i want to get latest data from the database

```go
    func WebsoValue(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        var device []Humid
        DB.Find(&device)
        return c.JSON(device)
    }
```

Comment: Could you please describe what is not working for you as expected?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the latest data using `Interval` with the help of `Raw Query`.

Here is a sample example for your scenario:

```
    func WebsoValue(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
      
            var device []Humid
            DB.Raw("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL '5 minutes'"
).Scan(&device)
            return c.JSON(device)
        }
```

Make sure, You do the error handling while scanning the data.